# Is it possible to add custom widgets/scripts to a facebook status update?

Tags: facebook, flash, iframe, widget

We would like to be able for our users to share a widget on their facebook status instead of the normal text/link/video that is common.
Something more advanced like the Spotify widget.

I have searched around, but not finding many answers, so I'm wondering if this is possible and how can it be done?

Comment: Can only be done with flash, keyword is “feed gaming”.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but are there any limits to the kind of flash app interaction?